# Making an obfuscated exe Primary Output of a WinForm Setup project

Tags: obfuscation, setup-project

I'm using DotFuscator to obfuscate my source code.  How do I make the obfuscated file, which lives in a separate directory, the primary output of my Setup project?  If I overwrite file in obj and release folders with obfuscated file, it just gets overwritten my I recompile Setup project.

Thanks.
Charlie

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Dotfuscator project first, i.e right click on solution->add project->select Dotfuscator as project type. To the project created right click on Input-> map to project output from your actual project. Build the Dotfuscator project. Next add the setup project. Point setup project output to that of Dotfuscator. And now build to create the setup. Now your code is obfuscated.

Comment: I don't see Dotfuscator listed as a project type

Comment: can any one tell me how to add Dotfuscator template in visual studio 2010